# Getting an executing processes full path in Windows XP

Tags: c++, windows-xp

So i need to get a list of processes running on a computer and then get the full path of each process. (Im looking for the folder each process is run from). I was using QueryFullProcessImageName - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684919(v=vs.85).aspx however ive only just found out that this code needs to work on Windows XP and that functions minimum client is Vista.

So does anyone know of another way of doing this?

I was trying to use GetModuleFileNameEx but it just wouldnt work. I would pass in the Process handle and all i would get back in the output was "íííííííííííííííííííííííííííííííííííí".

EDIT: Here was my attempt to use GetModuleFileNameEx:

```
HANDLE hProcessSnap;
PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;
string name = procName;

// Take a snapshot of all processes in the system.
hProcessSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
if (hProcessSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    REPORT_ERROR("CreateToolhelp32Snapshot (of processes): err=%d\n", ::GetLastError());
    return false;
}

// Set the size of the structure before using it.
pe32.dwSize = sizeof(pe32);

// Retrieve information about the first process,
// and exit if unsuccessful
if( !Process32First(hProcessSnap, &pe32))
{
    REPORT_ERROR("Process32First: err=%d\n", ::GetLastError());  // Show cause of failure
    CloseHandle(hProcessSnap);     // Must clean up the snapshot object!
    return false;
}
char pName[MAX_PATH];

//iterate through all processes
do {
    //Find start of files name
    char *szProcessFilename = strchr(pe32.szExeFile, '\\');
    if (szProcessFilename == NULL)
        szProcessFilename = pe32.szExeFile;
    else
        szProcessFilename++;    //Skip over last slash

    if (_stricmp(procName, szProcessFilename) == 0)
    {
        HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess( PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, false, pe32.th32ProcessID );
        char procLocationChar[MAX_PATH];
        DWORD exe_path_size = MAX_PATH;
        DWORD s = GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess, NULL, pName, exe_path_size);
```

I do some more stuff after this to get the path, but the value of pName is just "ÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ"

Comment: How did you look at the output? May be post the code you tried with GetModuleFileNameEx

Comment: I was debugging and stepping through. Ill edit the first post

Comment: Actually found what was wrong with my code. I left the PROCESS_VM_READ out of the OpenProcess call

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of processes you can use [EnumProcesses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function from PSAPI. The use [OpenProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the resulting PIDs in turn and [GetModuleFileNameEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on their handles to retrieve executable name. Something like this:

```
const size_t maxPids = 1024;

std::set<std::wstring> processes;

DWORD pids[maxPids] = {};
DWORD bytesReturned = 0;

if (::EnumProcesses(pids, sizeof pids, &bytesReturned))
{
    DWORD cProcesses = bytesReturned / sizeof *pids;

    // set SeDebug privilege

    for (DWORD i = 0; i < cProcesses; i++)
    {
        DWORD pid = pids[i];

        if (HANDLE hProcess = ::OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, pid))
        {
            WCHAR filename[MAX_PATH] = {};

            if (::GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess, NULL, filename, MAX_PATH))
            {
                processes.insert(filename);
            }
            else
            {
                // handle error
            }

            ::CloseHandle(hProcess);
        }
        else
        {
            // handle error
        }
    }

    // disable SeDebug privilege
}
else
{
    // handle error
}
```

Note that there are some processes which can not be opened (system, idle, etc.). You may want to filter them first or just ignore errors. Also, depending on system environment, you might need special privileges to open processes not created by you (SeDebugPrivilege), see documentation on OpenProcess function.